# stateless component doesn't receive new props after action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a react component,ReorderComponent, which renders a list passed by a redux store.
I wrapped the list in a Reorder component from 'react-reorder' and when the user changes the order of the list, i have a dipatch function passed as props that updates the store.

This steps are done sucessfully, as i can see the store update, and the Main Container receiving a new state, with the reordered list.

However, my ReorderComponent doesnot update it's props when the state changes.

The structure is the following:

-RequestContainer.js

- receives the state and maps state and dipsatch to props

-connects to the ReorderComponent

-ReorderComponent.js

-stateless component which receives props to render list and handle re order event.

```html
import React from 'react'
import CitiesListReorder from '../components/CitiesListReorder'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { setCity, setOrder, removeCity, setNumDays, setPreferences } from '../actions'

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log('passing as props:\ncities', state[Object.keys(state).length - 1].cities)
  return {
    cities: state[Object.keys(state).length - 1].cities,
    fID: Object.keys(state).length -1,
    preferences: state[Object.keys(state).length - 1].preferences,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onRemoveClick: (fID, index) => {
      dispatch(removeCity(fID, index))
    },
    onEditClick: (fID, value, index) => {
      dispatch(setCity(fID, value, index))
    },
    onSetNumDays: (fID, index, days ) => {
      dispatch(setNumDays(fID, index, days))
    },
    onSetPrefences: (fID, pref_type, info) => {
      dispatch(setPreferences(fID, pref_type, info))
    },
    onReOrder: (fID, prevIndex, nextIndex) => {
      dispatch(setOrder(fID, prevIndex, nextIndex))
    }
  }
}

const RequestContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(CitiesListReorder)

export default RequestContainer
```

```html
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import City  from '../components/City'
import removeCity from '../actions'
import Preferences from './Preferences'
import Reorder, { reorder, reorderImmutable, reorderFromTo, reorderFromToImmutable } from 'react-reorder';


const CitiesListReorder = ({ fID, cities, preferences, onRemoveClick,
  onEditClick, onSetNumDays, onSetPrefences, onReOrder }) => {
  console.log('inside cities list reorder')
  return(
    <div>
      <Reorder
        reorderId="my-list"
        reorderGroup="reorder-group"
        component="ul"
        placeholderClassName="placeholder"
        draggedClassName="dragged"
        lock="horizontal"
        holdTime={100}
        onReorder={ (event, prevIndex, nextIndex) => {onReOrder(fID, prevIndex, nextIndex)} }
        autoScroll={true}
        disabled={false}
        disableContextMenus={true}
        placeholder={
          <div className="custom-placeholder" />
        }
      >
        {
          cities.map((city, index) => (
            <li key = {'li' + index} >
              <City
                key = {'city' + index}
                cityIndex = {index}
                city = {city}
                flightID = {fID}
                onRemoveClick = { onRemoveClick }
                onEditClick = { onEditClick }
              />
          </li>
          ))
        }
      </Reorder>
      {cities.length > 1
        ?
            <Preferences
            fID = { fID }
            numCities = { cities.length }
            preferences = { preferences }
            onSetPrefences = { onSetPrefences }
          />
        :
          null
      }
    </div>
  )
}

CitiesListReorder.propTypes = {
  fID: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  cities: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  preferences: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  onRemoveClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onEditClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onSetNumDays: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onSetPrefences: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onReOrder: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}


export default CitiesListReorder
```

[image]

in this image we can see that after the state change, the dumb component did not update its props, since it did not log anything.

Reducer:

```html
case SET_ORDER:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.fID]: Object.assign(
          {},
          state[action.fID],
          {cities: setOrder(state[action.fID].cities, action.prevIndex, action.nextIndex)}
        )
      }
      
 export function setOrder(cities, prevIndex, nextIndex){
  var first = cities[prevIndex]
  var second = cities[nextIndex]
  var newList = cities
  newList[prevIndex] = second
  newList[nextIndex] = first
  return newList
}
```

Comment: Can you show your reducer?  Per the Redux FAQ, 99% of the time ["my component didn't update" is due to state mutation](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-not-rerendering).

Comment: Also, as a side note: you can simplify your action dispatching using the "object shorthand" for connect. Just pass an object as the second argument, like : `{onRemoveClick : removeCity, onEditClick : setCity}`.

Comment: I added the respective reducer functions. @markerikson

Comment: also, how can i verify if i made a mistake by mutating the state? i am writing test units, but if the state mutaded, aparently i did a mistake there also, because the tests are passing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your `setOrder` function is mutating the state.  Pasting it in for reference:

```
 export function setOrder(cities, prevIndex, nextIndex){
  var first = cities[prevIndex]
  var second = cities[nextIndex]
  var newList = cities
  newList[prevIndex] = second
  newList[nextIndex] = first
  return newList
}
```

In that function, `newList` is still pointing to the *same array* as `cities`.  In order for this to work properly, you need to make a *copy* of `cities`, and modify the copy.  So, you just need to do `var newList = cities.slice()`.

This is one of the issues I talked about in the [Immutable Update Patterns](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) page in the Redux docs (and specifically, "Common Mistake #2").

There's also several existing utilities that can freeze your state and detect mutations in development.  See the DevTools#Linting section of my [Redux addons catalog](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/devtools.md#linting).